# why code not working althoug it looks okay to me?

Tags: php, arrays, function, web-scraping

I previously found a script while googling and used it for scrapping purpose, my main class

in my amazon.php, I wrote the following script

```
include('scrape.php');
set_time_limit(0);


$ASIN       =   'B000GEM3RI';
$shipArray  =   shipingPrice($ASIN);
var_dump($shipArray);
print_r($shipArray);
echo $shipArray;



function shipingPrice($city){
        $shipArray = array();
        $scrape = new Scrape();
        $url = 'http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/'.$city.'/ref=dp_olp_new?ie=UTF8&condition=new';
        $scrape->fetch($url);
        $data = $scrape->removeNewlines($scrape->result);
        $data = $scrape->fetchBetween('<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0"> <thead class="columnheader"><tr><th scope="col" class="price">Price + Shipping</th><th scope="col" class="condition">Condition</th><th scope="col" class="seller">Seller Information</th><th scope="col" class="readytobuy">Buying Options</th></tr></thead>','</table>',$data,true); 
        $rows = $scrape->fetchAllBetween('<tr','</tr>',$data,true);
        $i=0;$j=0;
        foreach ($rows as  $row){
            if($i!=0){
                if($i!=2){              
                    $record = array();
                    $cells = $scrape->fetchAllBetween('<td','</td>',$row,true);                 
                    $record['price'] = strip_tags($cells[0]);
                    
                    if(stristr($record['price'],'oz')===False && stristr($record['price'],'/')===False)
                    {
                        $listPrice=$scrape->fetchBetween('$',' +',$record['price']);
                    }else{
                        $listPrice=$scrape->fetchBetween('$',' (',$record['price']);
                    }
                    //print_r($listPrice);
                    if($listPrice==''){
                        $listPrice=$scrape->fetchBetween('$',' &',$record['price']);
                        $shipPrice='0';                     
                    }else{
                        $shipPrice=$scrape->fetchBetween('+ $','s',$record['price']);
                    }
                    $shipPrice= floatval($shipPrice);
                    //####                  
                    $sellerIdInfo = $cells[2];                                          $sellerIdArray=$scrape->fetchAllBetween('&marketplaceSeller=0&seller=','"><b>',$sellerIdInfo);                  
                    if(count($sellerIdArray)>1){
                        $sellerId=$sellerIdArray[0];
                    }else{
                        $temp = explode('"id',$sellerIdArray[0]);
                        $sellerId=$temp[0];                                         
                    }
                    //##
                    $sellerName =$scrape->fetchBetween('Seller:','Seller',$record['price']);                    
                    $sellerInfo=$scrape->fetchAllBetween('alt="','"',$cells[2],true);           
                    $sellerName=str_replace(array('alt="','"'),array('',''),$sellerInfo[0]);
                    if($sellerName!=""){        
                        //
                    }else{
                        $sellerName = $scrape->fetchBetween('<span class="sellerHeader">Seller:</span>','</b></a>',$cells[2],true);
                        $sellerName=str_replace("Seller:","",$sellerName);
                        $sellerName=$scrape->fetchBetween('<b>','</b>',$sellerName);            
                    }

                    array_push($shipArray,array('sellerName'=>$sellerName,'sellerId'=>$sellerId,'price'=>$listPrice,'shipPrice'=>$shipPrice));

                }
            }
            $i++;
        }
        return $shipArray;
}
```

the url for this scrip is [amazon](http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B000GEM3RI/ref=dp_olp_new?ie=UTF8&condition=new)

when I echo it, var_dump it or print_r, an empty array is displayed, I checked the page using firebug and to me, looks like everything is okay in my code

can somebody tell me why I can access anything from the page although my code is okay?

thanks for helping me

**EDIT:-**

By adding return `$this->result = curl_exec($ch);` in my scrap class function fetch($url), I have assured that Page is being retrieved successfullly...

**EDIT-2:-**

after working on the advice as provided in answer, it tried

```
$shipArray[]=array('sellerName'=>$sellerName,'sellerId'=>$sellerId,'price'=>$listPrice,'shipPrice'=>$shipPrice);
```

in my function, but still the same empty array

EDIT-3

I changed the following function

```
function fetchBetween($needle1,$needle2,$haystack,$include=false){
        
        $position = strpos($haystack,$needle1);
        
        if ($position === false) { return ' it was null data'; }
```

when I echo `echo $data;` in my script file,

> it was null data

is printed, so looks like this line of code `$position = strpos($haystack,$needle1);` is not working,

am I right?

if yes, what to do now?

Comment: What debugging have you done already?

Comment: I am tried var_dump(),print_r(), I opened the page to see whether its exists or not, I saw the html node tree to see whether I am missing some tag ..things like these

Comment: Why does you constructor returns something?

Comment: scrapping class is not mine, I found it while googling for something, I wrote the function to utilize it, and the logic I got for returning true is that the constructor initiated the object successfully

Comment: @NewBee - have you checked to see whether your code is connecting OK to the site? And that the data you're getting back is formatted as you expect it to be?

Comment: I did it by manually constructing the URL (by passing ASIN as city to the code and visting the URL in FF), I have not an idea how to check this via code

Comment: @andrewsi see the update on my quetion please

Comment: @NewBee - then do a var_dump on $data and $rows and make sure there's content in there, too.

Comment: @andrewsi when I do var_dump on $rows, its empty array, same with $data

Comment: @NewBee; alright - what's in `$scrape->result`?

Comment: By adding return $this->result = curl_exec($ch); in my scrap class function fetch($url), I have assured that Page is being retrieved successfullly...If I do so, page is properly displayed in broswer

Comment: @andrewsi looks faulty to me  

 function fetchBetween($needle1,$needle2,$haystack,$include=false){
  
  $position = strpos($haystack,$needle1);
  
  if ($position === false) { return ' it was null data'; }

and in my amazon.php file , I added echo $data;

when I run the script, "it was null data" is printed, so it looks like $position is having issue, am I right?

Comment: @NewBee - It looks like you're looking for data in a particular format; and the format that the data you're getting isn't what your code is expecting. Look at the data you have in `$scrape` and figure out what you're actually getting, and change the first parameter of `fetchBetween` to that.

Comment: @andrewsi can you guide me a bit more please? you have the URL of the page, you have the complete code, please guide me what and how I should change,

Comment: @NewBee - sorry, I'm not going to do your job for you.

Comment: @andrewsi thanks for you time, I am stuck at this point , any how, really really thanks for all of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotcha, I was correct, issue was not with my code

on line

```
 $data = $scrape->fetchBetween('<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0"> <thead class="columnheader"><tr><th scope="col" class="price">Price + Shipping</th><th scope="col" class="condition">Condition</th><th scope="col" class="seller">Seller Information</th><th scope="col" class="readytobuy">Buying Options</th></tr></thead>','</table>',$data,true);
```

there was an extra space `border="0"> <thead class`, that was creating issue, once, I removed this the space from

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0"><thead class="columnheader">
```

my code became okay..

thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

Why are you defining a var as the result of a function that hasn't been defined yet?

```
$shipArray  =   shipingPrice($ASIN);
var_dump($shipArray);
print_r($shipArray);
echo $shipArray;
```

ShippingPrice function is lower in the code. IE shipArray  will be empty

Comment: You can use functions before they are declared in PHP code, the pre-parser will make sure they are declared correctly.

Comment: can you do an array push with an array? Wouldn't you do $shipArray = $shipArray + $otherArray? in your loop? I lied that won't work if keys are the same

Comment: @AlexReynolds I am not getting you enough, can you point me to code, or edit only specific lines of code?

Comment: array_push($shipArray,array('sellerName'=>$sellerName,'sellerId'=>$sellerId,'price'=>$listPrice,'shipPrice'=>$shipPrice)). I'm unsure if you can push an array onto another multidimensional array. of if you should do $shipArray[] = array('sellerName'=>$sellerName,'sellerId'=>$sellerId,'price'=>$listPrice,'shipPrice'=>$shipPrice).

Comment: @NewBee are you at least getting data back from $scrape->fetch($url)?